How to Model Installment Payments with Different Durations Using Survival Analysis?
I'm working on a problem where I need to model the likelihood of future payments for various installment plans using survival analysis. The data I have consists of installment payment plans (or agreements) of different lengths, some of which have been fully paid, some are ongoing, and some have defaulted.
Each agreement (think of it like a loan or payment plan) has a unique identifier, a total number of installments, and information about whether each installment was paid on time, late, or missed. Here's a simplified version of the data:



Agreement ID
Installment Due Date
Installment Number
Amount Due
Payment Status
Agreement Status
Customer Type




101
2022-01-15
1
100.00
Paid Late
Fully Paid
A


101
2022-02-15
2
100.00
Paid Late
Fully Paid
A


102
2022-01-15
1
200.00
Not Paid
Open
B


102
2022-02-15
2
200.00
Not Paid
Open
B


103
2022-03-15
1
150.00
Paid On Time
Defaulted
A



Problem:
Each agreement has a predetermined total number of installments (e.g., 12, 24, 36 months), and I know the maximum number of installments upfront. The goal is to predict the probability of each future installment being paid based on the number of installments already paid, the total amount due, the customer type, etc. However, I have several challenges:
Different Agreement Lengths: Each agreement can have a different number of installments (e.g., 12, 24, 60 months). Agreements with fewer installments may behave differently than those with more installments, so how should this be handled in the model?
Known Agreement Duration: Unlike typical survival problems where the event (e.g., death) could happen at any unknown time, here we know exactly how long the agreement can last (e.g., 24 months). How do I incorporate this known duration into a survival analysis model?
Status and Default Definition: If a customer misses 3 consecutive payments, we consider the agreement as defaulted, and they cannot make further payments. Should this be treated as a "death" in survival analysis, and how would that interact with ongoing agreements that haven't defaulted yet?
Predicting Conditional Probabilities: I want to predict the conditional probability of paying the next installment given the number of past payments, the amount paid so far, and how many installments are left. For instance, if an agreement has 60 installments and 5 have been paid, how would the model adjust predictions differently from an agreement with 20 total installments and 5 paid?
What I've Tried:
I initially applied a Cox Proportional Hazards model but found that the probabilities decline too quickly and are overly influenced by the agreements with longer durations. My concern is that agreements with fewer installments may converge too quickly to a default probability influenced by those with longer terms. I also thought about a time-varying covariate model but am unsure if this is the best approach when the maximum duration is known upfront.
Key Questions:
How can I effectively model these different installment durations in a survival analysis framework, considering I know the maximum duration for each agreement?
Is Cox Proportional Hazards the right approach, or should I consider a parametric model like Weibull or a different technique altogether?
How do I handle the scenario where agreements have a known "death" (default) after 3 missed payments?
What are the best ways to evaluate and compare the performance of these models, especially when predicting payment behavior for both short and long installment plans?
Any guidance or recommendations for dealing with these challenges, especially in structuring the data for survival analysis, would be greatly appreciated!

Is there any reason why you want to model the using tools from survival analysis specifically? You describe your aim as “I want to predict the conditional probability of paying the next installment given (…)”. To do this a logistic regression model or decision tree might be a good - and simple - start. It would be a more direct approach than to use survival theory. It is not clear to me which model you have fitted but I assume you have done something like first estimate a baseline hazard, then estimate the parameters in a Cox-PH model, then combine these to estimate the survival curve, then take the median and see if it is later than the next installment. In a logistic regression you simply estimate the probability that the next installment will be paid. You can then say e.g. if the probability is below 50% then you can simply take it as a prediction that the next payment will fail. If this leads to too many type I errors (false positives i.e. false predictions that the payment will fail) you can change the threshold to e.g. 30% and evaluate the model there to see if you are more satisfied with this level of type I errors.
Regarding evaluation there are many resources on evaluating prediction models only. For binary predictions (installment payed/not payed) you can google “accuracy” and “precision” e.g. I would also advise you to google test, training and validation set. But first, you have to think through what the model is going to be used for. A fundamental trade-off is between false positives and false negatives - how important is to catch someone why fails to pay vs. what are the costs of making a wrong prediction? A prediction model is to be used in a context and that context pretty much determines how the model is to be evaluated.

Welcome to Cross Validated! Thanks for contributing. Good point about using binomial regression instead of a (continuous-time) Cox model. As this is evaluating event probabilities over time, it might still be called a "discrete-time" survival model, but that's just a name for a binary regression (typically with a logit or complementary log-log link) on properly formatted data. Your point about evaluating costs instead of accuracy/precision is also well taken. (+1)
